# MLX90640 Sensor data performance drop when all the data is being recorded through i2c (Python)

Tags: python, performance, optimization, sensors, adafruit

I don't really know how to phrase this question as I dont know what the exact problem is, however, I have narrowed it down to what is causing the problem in my code.

I am working with an MLX90640 thermal sensor and my current goal is to reach its maximum frame rate of near 60hz. After tinkering with the Adafruit_mlx90640 Library, I have managed to get an output of roughly 57 FPS, but this frame rate is short-lived. After about 5 seconds of the code running, the frame rate slowly drops to below 30 FPS and I can't figure out why.

For a quick summary of the sensor, it uses a 24x32 array of IR sensors which provides 768 pixels of data. This data is stored in the variable "frameData". As shown in the commented part of the code. This is the line that is used for receving the data from the sensor is what causes the performance loss. After messing around with this line of code, when the end value is set to anything lower then around 270 (I used 256 as its just 768/3, end=256), the code retains its frame rate, however anything higher and the frame rate drops after those first 5 seconds. The picture attached below shows the full framedata variable printed within the first 5 seconds. The code with end=256 only stores the first 256 values in the framedata variable.

If anyone has an idea why this may be happening/ways to fix or correct this, I am all ears. I dont know if its a problem with the i2c bus not being able to keep up, or if its a problem with the speed of python coding, so anything helps. Also if you need any more information I would be glad to provide it.

Thank you.

Specifications:

- Raspberry Pi 4 4Gb
- i2c bus is set at 1000000 in sudo nano /boot/config.txt
- Sensors frame rate is set at 64Hz

Picture of printed variable "framedata" when end=768
[image: Picture of printed variable "framedata" when end=768]

The important parts of the modified Adafruit_Mlx90640 Library.

```
def _GetFrameData(self):
        dataReady = 0
        cnt = 0
        statusRegister = [0]
        controlRegister = [0]
        data = [0]*64
        framedata = [0] * 834 
        
        while dataReady == 0:
            self._I2CReadWords(0x8000, statusRegister)
            dataReady = statusRegister[0] & 0x0008

        self._I2CWriteWord(0x8000, 0x0030)

        #The line below is the line that causes the performance loss
        #If I change the end value to around 256 (end=256), then the performance drop doesn't occur.

        self._I2CReadWords(0x0400, frameData, end=768) #end=768

        self._I2CReadWords(0x0700, data, end=64)
        self._I2CReadWords(0x800D, controlRegister)
        frameData[832] = controlRegister[0]
        frameData[833] = statusRegister[0] & 0x0001
        return frameData[833]    

def _I2CReadWords(self, addr, buffer, *, end=None):
        #stamp = time.monotonic()

        if end is None:
            remainingWords = len(buffer)
        else:
            remainingWords = end

        offset = 0
        addrbuf = bytearray(2)
        inbuf = bytearray(2 * I2C_READ_LEN)

        with self.i2c_device as i2c:
            while remainingWords:
                addrbuf[0] = addr >> 8  # MSB
                addrbuf[1] = addr & 0xFF  # LSB
                read_words = min(remainingWords, I2C_READ_LEN)
                
                #This is the code that reads the i2c bus (Im assuming)
                i2c.write_then_readinto(addrbuf, inbuf, in_end=read_words * 2)

                outwords = struct.unpack(">" + "H" * read_words, inbuf[0 : read_words * 2])

                for i, w in enumerate(outwords):
                    buffer[offset + i] = w
                offset += read_words
                remainingWords -= read_words
                addr += read_words
```

---

### Line Profiler Data

Line Profiler Data in the first 5 seconds of running the code
[image]

Line Profiler Data after around 5 seconds of running the code
[image]

Comment: 64Hz is very slow so Python should have no problems handling that frame rate. Mayby some part of your code is inefficient. Try `line_profiler` to check where is bottleneck. Measure it running both for 5seconds and then for ~50seconds - and then compare - take a look what has gotten noticeable slower for 50sec run

Comment: Thank you, I will do this and get back with the results

Comment: @dankal444 I added the Line Profiler data to the post, it appears to be the i2c.write_then_readinto line that is taking the most time. I don't know much about the i2c bus optimizing this is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: You will need to make longer profiling than single function call. You can do that by 1) using different profiling decorator (last function [in this file](https://github.com/ooda/cloudly/blob/42f28ebe1ec732ddd801f204cb33201a8ce192e9/cloudly/decorators.py)), 2) adding this decorator (`line_profile`) to main function 3) adding functions to argument `follow` of the decorator